# How to use FormArray in child component with methods inside parent

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I am building form in angular 6 with reactive form and i am using components for each section and i have some problems:
How can i use FormArray in child component with methods inside the parent.
for example:

in the parent ts file:

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
  _server: this.fb.array([this.initItemRows()]),
   })
 }


  initItemRows() {
    return this.fb.group({
      // DocumentID:  uuid(),
      HostName: [],
      IPAddress: [],
      Domain: [],
      OS: []
    });
}


  get serverForms() {
    return this.parentForm.get('_server') as FormArray
  }

  addServer() {

    const server = this.fb.group({ 
      // DocumentID:  uuid(),
      HostName: [],
      IPAddress: [],
      Domain: [],
      OS: []
    })

    this.serverForms.push(server);
  }

  deleteServer(i) {
    this.serverForms.removeAt(i)
  }
```

in the parent html i have:

```
<div formArrayName="_server">
    <table id="_server" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Host name</th>
                <th>IP</th>
                <th>Domain</th>
                <th>OS</th>
                <th>action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr *ngFor="let server of serverForms.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <td>
                    <input formControlName="HostName" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input formControlName="IPAddress" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input formControlName="Domain" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input formControlName="OS" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td class="buttonCenter">
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="deleteFieldButton" (click)="deleteServer(i)" type="button">delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="addFieldButton" (click)="addServer()" type="button">insert row</button>

    </table>
</div>
```

but i want to use all the html code of the parent (above) to be in a child components

```
 <app-servers-section></app-servers-section>
```

I know that i can use  FormGroupDirective inside the child component but its not working when i need to use the parents methods.

Please advice!
Thanks!

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Comment: @Chellappan i created project but it's not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxzwkn

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

```
 <app-servers-section (changeInChildForm)="doSomething($event)"></app-servers-section>
```

and in the Child Component, where you want to keep your form, you need to emit an event from there.

so, in your ChildComponent.ts import **EventEmitter** and **Output** with Component and other things

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
```

and in the body of Class you can do something like this to emit the event you want to pass to parent from child.

```
@Output() changeInChildForm = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  somethingHappenedInChild(data: any) {
    this.changeInChildForm.emit(data);
  }
```

So, when you want to emit a change from children, call the method `somethingHappenedInChild` of Child Component. `changeInChildForm` will emitted, It will call the method `doSomething($event)` of Parent component.

I didn't create a stackblitz. But if you want more help regarding this, create one stackblitz as others mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. i created project but it's not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxzwkn